# UAP-AC-LITE very slow

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ubiquiti

I get internet over a Vodafone wireless router. Wired and wireless, a speed test (reproduced several times over the last month) shows 220 Mbps with a wireless connection.

To have internet in the whole building, I decided to buy UAP-AC-LITE access points (currently only one for testing purposes) and ubiquiti ER-X-SFP for POE.

Setup: WAN -- Vodafone -- ER-X-SFP -- UAP-AC-LITE

However, connecting my laptop to the UAP-AC-LITE, the speed test shows only 30 Mbps. Connecting to the ER-X-SFP over Ethernet gets my 180 Mbps. The Vodafone wireless connection still gets me 220 Mbps. My laptop is 1m away from the AP.

What could be the problem? Is ubiquiti just garbage? If yes, what should I get to have wireless in the entire building?

Comment: I have a Ubquitii Lite AP on my second floor and speed is excellent. Make sure firmware is up to date and make sure the controller software is properly set up and working.

Comment: What standard of WiFi does your laptop support. The access point is WiFi 5. Additional details is required.

Comment: WiFi 5. It is a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga (4. Generation)

Comment: Firmware is most resent. Updated last week.